# Grunt | Compile subfolders + including pug files

Tags: gruntjs, pug-loader

In this current situation grunt does watch the files in subfolder but there is no compilation to dist.
See (part) of my gruntfile:

```js
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('./package.json'),
        config: {
            dist: './dist',
            src: './src',
            htmlPath: '<%= config.dist %>'
        },

        watch: {
            options: {
                spawn: false
            },
            pug: {
                files: '<%= config.src %>/**/*.pug',
                tasks: ['pug:dist']
            }
        },

        pug: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    pretty: true,
                    data: {
                        debug: false
                    }
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.src %>',
                    src: ['*.pug'],
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
                    ext: '.html',
                }]
            }
        },
    });
```

I am guessing this probally because of includes folders and such (that should appear in dist folder). How can I modify my setup so grunt does compile some specific subfolders and files within?